# Find and display all existing blocks in simulink library browser

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am looking for a method to display all the blocks and libraries that exist in Simulink library browser. I was able to display the blocks for each model but I'm trying to display all the blocks that exist in Simulink library browser. 
Thank you

Comment: Doesn't the Library Browser, by definition, list and display all the libraries and blocks available in the Library Browser?  What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to save the list of blocks of each library in a ".txt" file